# gtk#: remove a column by its column name

Tags: mono, treeview, gtk#, gtk2

I have a TreeView in GTK# and want to remove specific columns.
How can I achieve this?

TreeView.RemoveColumn() sounds good, but I've got no idea how to find the desired columns by their names.

Thinking of something like
TreeView.RemoveColumn( TreeView.FindColumn("address"));

I really have no idea... :'-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a sequential search over the columns, this way:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds a column by its title.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The first <see cref="Gtk.TreeViewColumn"/> with that title.</returns>
    /// <param name="tv">The given <see cref="Gtk.TreeView"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="title">The title to look for.</param>
    static Gtk.TreeViewColumn FindColumnByTitle(Gtk.TreeView tv, string title)
    {
        Gtk.TreeViewColumn toret = null;

        title = title.ToLower();
        foreach(Gtk.TreeViewColumn column in tv.Columns) {
            if ( column.Title.ToLower() == title ) {
                toret = column; 
                break;
            }
        }

        return toret;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, this does the job!
Appreciating your answer!